# Can you switch between ui-router views without switching tabs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am using Ionic and Angular 1 (with ui-router). Let's say I have 2 tabs:

```
+----+   +-------+
|HOME|   |PROFILE|
+----+   +-------+
```

This is the important part: there's a link within the `HOME` tab to `/profile`... *but*, I do not want it to automatically switch to the `PROFILE` tab when I click that link... I want to continue with the navigation stack *within* the `HOME` tab.

The usual approach using ui-router to have multiple nested states is something [like this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views) (some unnecessary things for this example purposefully omitted):

```
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  template: require('templates/app.html'),
})
.state('app.home', {
  template: require('templates/home.html'),
  url: '/home',
  controller: 'HomeCtrl',
  views: {
    // a bunch of child views that can only belong to this state
  }
})
.state('app.profile', {
  template: require('templates/profile.html'),
  url: '/profile',
  controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
  views: {
    // a bunch of child views that can only belong to this state
  }
});
```

But what if I want to navigate to `app.profile` **inside of** `app.home`, instead of being forced to change tabs?

One options is to make all my tabs abstract and then declare `<tab>.<state>` for every possible state (using a loop), but this seems like it requires a lot of possibly unnecessary overhead:

```
var abstractStates = [
  {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    template: require('templates/home.html')
  },
  {
    name: 'profile',
    url: '/profile',
    controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
    template: require('templates/profile.html')
  }
];

abstractStates.forEach(function(state) {
  $stateProvider.state(state.name, _.omit(state, ['name']);

  abstractStates.forEach(function(nestedState) {
    $stateProvider.state([state.name, nestedState.name].join('.'), _.omit(nestedStates, ['abstract', 'name']));
  });
});
```

**Is there a better way to accomplish this?**

Comment: So are you saying that you want the tab contents for the Home tab to change to the tab contents for the Profile tab when you click on a link in the Home tab, but not change anything around it? In other words, you want to reuse the profile tab view and controller, but not change to the profile state? If the latter, could you use a directive to encapsulate all the profile tab functionality and include it in both places?

Comment: @GregL, thanks for your comment. I think it doesn't necessarily need to be represented as a directive, since a template and a controller can be declared for a state, as far as I understand. I think creating a directive would just be duplicating work.

Comment: @GregL, as far as your other questions, yes.